# How to create seperate files for each set of Dialogs in Azure bot framework - Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

I am having 5 different categories of dialogs.
I wanted to keep each of them in seperate files like - Dialog1.js, Dialog2.js, and so on.

Could some one help me on the same?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. Here we are creating dialogs in some different files, but registering the dialogs with bot by importing them to index.js and calling `bot.dialog("<dialog name>", <dialog>)`. You can build on this to have many dialogs registered with bot.

*This keeps the dialog code short and separate.*

**dialog1.js**

```
const dialog1 = [function(session){
    session.send("this is dialog 1");
}];

module.exports = {
    dialog: dialog1
}
```

**dialog2.js**

```
const dialog2 = [function(session){
    session.send("this is dialog 2");
}];

module.exports = {
    dialog: dialog2
}
```

**index.js**

```
const dialog1 = require("./dialog1.js").dialog;
const dialog2 = require("./dialog2.js").dialog;

....
bot.dialog("dialog1", dialog1);
bot.dialog("dialog2", dialog2);
```